# unix venv django-admin permission denied

Tags: python, django, unix, pip, permissions

I am trying to set up django project on a Linux CentOS system.
I have created a virtual environment like this:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

And activated it like this:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Within this virtual environment I updated pip like this:

```
(venv)$ python -m pip install -U pip
```

This returned the message below:

```
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
```

Next I installed django and djangorestframework like so:

```
(venv)$ python -m pip install django djangorestframework
```

This returned the message below:

```
Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 django-3.1.7 djangorestframework-3.12.2 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
```

I then tried to start a new project like this:

```
(venv)$ django-admin startproject myproject .
```

This is when I get the response:

```
-bash: /home/me/projects/venv/bin/django-admin: Permission denied
```

I don't think the solution to this should be a simple **chmod** on that file, because I think perhaps something is incorrect in how I installed things in the first place? Surely all permissions should be automatic considering I was working with (venv) activated? What am I missing here?

Comment: "*Surely all permissions should be automatic considering I was working with (venv) activated?*" Certainly. "*What am I missing here?*" How do we know? At least show us the permission: `ls -l /home/me/projects/venv/bin/django-admin` and the shebang: `head -1 /home/me/projects/venv/bin/django-admin`

Comment: For the first it is -rwxr-xr-x 1  and for the second it is  #!/home/me/projects/venv/bin/python

Comment: Both looks good. Puzzled…

Answer (score 0):

Ok puzzle solved. There was nothing wrong with any of the above. It turns out it was a security policy set to not allow any executables to run from /home at all. Moving my project to /opt solved everything.

Comment: I have the opposite problem.... I made it in home and moved it to /opt